# Load PageViewController After Asynchronous Task Complete

Tags: objective-c, swift, asynchronous

I'm having trouble loading the `PageViewController` after the async call is complete. I was considering using NSNotification, but not sure what is the best approach.

#### Async func to fetch images

```
func fetchArrayImages() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "FoodPhoto")
    query.orderByDescending("Votes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil){
            let imageObjects = objects as [PFObject]
            for object in objects {
                let photoUploaded = object["PhotoUploaded"] as PFFile
                photoUploaded.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        //image object implementation
                        self.photosUploadedArray.append(image!)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

#### Func to be called after async download images

This loads the `UIPageViewController`

```
func loadPhotosFromArray() {
    var array = photosUploadedArray
    view1 = PhotoCollevtionView(outerFrame: self.view.frame, photoArray: array, currentNumber: 0)
    self.view.addSubview(view1!)
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? you do not make clear why you can't call `loadPhotosFromArray`, although I can somehow guess it...

Comment: @sergio if I call `loadPhotosFromArray` before the async function is done loading, the array is empty. Is it possible to wait for the async function to complete before `loadPhotosFromArray`

Comment: you just need call it at the end of your completion block -- completion blocks are run when the async operation has completed... where did you exactly try to call it from?

Comment: @sergio so I need to add a completion block and then call it within the block?

Comment: @sergio would you mind showing me how to use the completion block to call after the async operation has completed?

Comment: The simplest strategy you could use is calling `loadPhotosFromArray` each time you get a new photo in (i.e., right after 'self.photosUploadedArray.append(image!)'. on the other hand, @szpetip suggestion about using a counter is pretty on the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your uploaded image is equals with last image in your imageObjects  array and in this case you can call your `loadPhotosFromArray()` code like this:

```
self.photosUploadedArray.append(image!)
if ( imageObjects.last.isEqual(image!)) { //Use this code
    loadPhotosFromArray()
 }
```

Comment: how can the OP be certain that the requests complete in the order they were made?

Comment: You're right, my other idea is using a counter to store the number of the uploaded images and compare the counter value with the size of the array in the place mentioned by me.

Comment: So i should create a counter for `photoUploaded` and when the size of `photosUploadedArray` is equal to the counter, then proceed with the function?

Comment: I think it should be work perfectly. Initialise the counter before the for loop, increase after the `self.photosUploadedArray.append(image!)` and then compare the counter with the size of the imageObjects.

I hope this help to you!